# java.io.StreamTokenizer.TT_NUMBER: Floating or Integer?

Tags: java, parsing

is there a way to find if the value parsed and returned by [java.io.StreamTokenizer](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/StreamTokenizer.html).**nval** (e.g. `200`)  was an integer or a floating number ?

Thanks

**Edited**:

I want to be able to know if the input was '200' or '200.0'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it is possible with StringTokenizer, it's too old. You can use Scanner to do the job:

```
Scanner fi = new Scanner("string 200 200.0");
fi.useLocale(Locale.US);

while (fi.hasNext()) {
    if (fi.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("Integer: " + fi.nextInt());
    } else if (fi.hasNextDouble()) {
        System.out.println("Double: " + fi.nextDouble());
    } else {
        System.out.println("String: " + fi.next());
    }  
}
```

Documentation for the class is [here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would use the modulus operator:

```
if (yourNval % 1 > 0)
{
    // nval is floating point.
}
else
{
    // nval is an integer.
}
```

This works because modulus [works with floating point numbers](http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/15.html) in Java as well as integers.

UPDATE: Since you specify a need to distinguish integers from doubles with zero-value decimal portions, I think you'll have to do something like the following:

```
Double(yourNval).toString().indexOf('.');
```

So a more-complete function will look like:

```
if (yourNval % 1 > 0)
{
    // nval is floating point.
}
else
{
    // nval is an integer.

    // Find number of trailing zeroes.
    String doubleStr = Double(yourNval).toString();
    int decimalLoc = doubleStr.indexOf('.');
    int numTrailingZeroes = 0;

    if (decimalLoc > 0)
    {
        numTrailingZeroes = doubleStr.length() - decimalLoc - 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your anwser, but this doesn't tell me if the input was '200.0' or '200'.

Comment: I've added code above to determine the number of trailing zeroes an integer `nval` input contains. Your example, `200.0`, will result a `numTrailingZeroes` value of `1`.

Comment: Thanks again, again your solution uses the float value but doesn't tell me about the original token parsed by the StreamTokenizer .

Comment: If you know the integer value and the number of trailing zeroes, you know exactly what the token was.  I guess akf and myself really just don't understand your question then, since you've had to rephrase it twice.

Answer (score 0):

As you are essentially trying to figure out if a `double` is an `int` or not, you can create a `BigDecimal` and test its [`scale()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#scale()) method.  You could also use the `Math` static method [`floor()`](http://www.j2ee.me/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floor(double)) and test the return value against the original.

```
 if(Math.floor(myStreamTokenizer.nval) == myStreamTokenizer.navl)) {
     //treat it as an int
 } else {
     //treat it as a double
 }
```

Of the two, I would use the `Math.floor` option, as it would be more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for your anwser, but this doesn't tell me if the input was '200.0' or '200'.

Comment: as the field is a double, `200` will always be `200.0`.